# handle duplicates fields in psycopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am writing web app using Flask(Python3.4) & psycopg2 to connect to postgres 9.4 database.

I have option in my web app where user can write their own query and execute it using web app and get output in html table in response.

I'm using cursor as **conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)**
Which i can not change as it is used by other parts of web app also.

One of my user wrote SQL like below,

```
SELECT
name || ' - ' || address,
id,
salary || '; ' || id from company;
```

Output from psycopg2 **(Wrong)**:

```
?column?  id ?column?
text integer (4) text
500.55; 1   1   500.55; 1
500.55; 2   2   500.55; 2
500.55; 3   3   500.55; 3
500.55; 4   4   500.55; 4
999.99; 5   5   999.99; 5
```

Here the result I got is wrong, due to duplication of key/field name **?column?** the second occurrence overwrite the first one.

Expected output was:

```
?column?  id ?column?
text integer (4) text
AAA - XY    1   500.55; 1
BBB - ZZ    2   500.55; 2
ABC - YY    3   500.55; 3
ABC - CC    4   500.55; 4
ABC - DD    5   999.99; 5
```

Server side code which send response:

```
# Fetch the column info 
if cur.description is not None:
    colinfo = [desc for desc in cur.description]

# Any rows?
if cur.rowcount > 0:
   result = []
   try:
      for row in cur:
         result.append(dict(row))
   except psycopg2.ProgrammingError:
       result = None

# response for html table
return Response(
    response=json.dumps(colinfo, result),
    status=status,
    mimetype="text/json"
)
```

Please suggest, How can I fix this with minimal code change?

Meanwhile I have also raised issue with psycopg2,
https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/454

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: @xeor I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is that dictionary entries have to have unique keys. Column name can't be used as a key if there's going to be more than one column with the same name. However you could check for that and if there is a duplicate column name, make it unique somehow:

```
# Fetch the column info 
if cur.description is not None:
    colinfo = [desc for desc in cur.description]

# Any rows?
if cur.rowcount > 0:
   result = []
   rowdict = {}
   colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]

   try:
      for row in cur:
         rowdict = {}
         for x in range(0, len(row)):

             # make sure column name is unique, if not append index number
             if colnames[x] in rowdict:
                 rowdict[colnames[x] + "_" + str(x)] = row[x]
             else:
                 rowdict[colnames[x]] = row[x]

         result.append(rowdict)

   except psycopg2.ProgrammingError:
       result = None

# response for html table
return Response(
    response=json.dumps(colinfo, result),
    status=status,
    mimetype="text/json"
)
```

Depending on what you're doing on the client side, you may have to update colinfo as well to reflect any column name changes that were made. Another option would be to return a clear error message if there are duplicate column names so the user can take control over what column names they get back.

It's ultimately a bug in psycopg2 but it's only returning what postgres provides for column names in cases like this. It's not clear what it should do instead.

I'm assuming you've considered and dealt with the serious info security risks associated with executing SQL from a client. I'm not trying to be preachy but it's a public forum and I'd be remiss for not mentioning that in case anyone else is looking to do something like this.

Comment: Thanks, but that is work around for above scenario But I want to fix the issue itself as user can enter any query.

Sample:

`select 1 as A , 2 as B, 3 as A, 4 as C;`

Hope that's clarify my question :)

Comment: @nn33rma Yes that does clarify it. I can reproduce your problem. As I understand it, DictCursor uses OrderedDict rather than the standard Dict. You can still reference the columns by index: row[0], row[1], row[2], etc, but if you have duplicate column names, that last column with that name will effectively be the only column you can retrieve with that key. You can test to see if the length of the dictionary matches the number of keys. If it doesn't, you know you have a problem, but there is no way to retrieve multiple columns with the same key.

Comment: I can not do that because I have column mapping at client side, Please refer server side code which I have updated, As this is user dependent code can't hard code that :)

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer to use your code but modify the column name returned if there is more than one with the same name